# exception thrown in the pointer of singly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, linked-list, nodes

ok, I created a linked list using the Node class and List class. But whenever I run it using the List object, it throws an exception when I return the `head` in the `getHead()` function in `Node.cpp`
these are the files that I created please if anyone could know why this exception is coming it would be a blessing

```
//**NODE.h**
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
private:
    Node* head;
    int data;
public:
    Node();
    Node(int);   //insert data
    void setHead(Node*);
    Node* getHead();
    void setData(int);
    int getData();
    void printData(Node*);
};
```

```
//**Node.cpp**
#include"Node.h"

Node::Node(){
    //Node* head = new Node();
    head = NULL;
    data = 0;
}

Node::Node(int DATA){
    //Node* head = new Node();
    head = nullptr;
    data = DATA;
}

int Node::getData(){            //DATA SETTER
    return this->data;
}
void Node::setData(int DATA){   //DATA GETTER
    this->data = DATA;
}

Node* Node::getHead(){          
    return head;
}
void Node::setHead(Node* NextAddress){
    this->head = NextAddress;
}

void Node::printData(Node* node){
    while(node != nullptr){
        cout<< this->data <<"\n";
        node = node->head;
    }
}
```

```
//**List.h**
#include"Node.h"

class List : public Node{
private:
   Node* head;
   Node* current;
   Node* prevcurrent;
public:
   List();
   //void setList(int);
   void insertAtBack(Node* , int);
   void insertAtFront(Node* , int);
   bool search(int);
   void print();
   ~List();
};
```

```
//**List.cpp**
#include"List.h"

List::List(){
    head=nullptr;
    current=nullptr;
    prevcurrent=nullptr;
}

void List::insertAtBack(Node* head , int Data){
Node* newNode = new Node();
newNode->setData(Data);

newNode->setHead(head);     //sets the address of the next node into the newly added node
head = newNode;
}


void List::insertAtFront(Node* head, int Data) {
    Node* temp = new Node();

}

bool List::search(int num){
Node* temp = head;   
    while (temp->getHead()!=nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->getData() == num)
        {
            return true;
        }
        temp->setHead(temp->getHead());     //itereates the adress in the emp node to store the address of the next node fro the while loop
    }
    
}

void List::print(){
    Node* temp=head;
    while (temp->getHead() != nullptr)
    {
        cout<<temp->getData()<<" ";
    }
    
}

List::~List() {
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp->getHead() != nullptr)
    {
        Node* temp2 = temp;
        temp = temp->getHead();
        delete temp2;
    }
}
```

```
//**main.cpp**
#include"List.h"
int main(){
// cout<<"running\n";
// Node box(5);         this works
// cout<<box.getData();
List obj;
Node node;              //this will throw an exception
obj.insertAtBack(&node,5);
obj.print();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what exception do you see?

Comment: Aside: use member initializer lists in your constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is thrown due to print:

```
void List::print() {
    Node *temp = head;
    while (temp->getHead() != nullptr) {
        cout << temp->getData() << " ";
    }
}
```

Here, a check is missing if `temp` (or equally `head`) is a nullptr before you dereference it in `temp->getHead()`

Same on `List::~List`

Comment: so if i place a check that would mean I need to tell it that `if temp==nullptr` then (do what exactly?)

Comment: the exception ended however, it still doesn't print the 5 that I passed in it as the data  wanted to store in the node

Comment: you can place the check in your `while` just before you dereference so you dont crash, like: `while( temp && temp->getHead() != nullptr )`. If you are sure that crash can happen only on the first node, you can place it outside of the while, like `if ( head == nullptr ) return;` As i see it now though, this while will be an endless loop, `temp` is not changed in this `while`. You probably missed `temp = temp->getHead();` ?

Comment: 5 is not printed because function `ínsertAtBack` will not add the data in the list, but it will create a new `Node` and add it under the `Node` object of `main` which does not participate the list. In general, `Node` should be an internal imlementation detail of the list. Clients of the list should not bother with Nodes, they should only be adding data to the list

Comment: i still dont understand how do i make a lot of nodes in my list to store the numbers 1 to 10 and then print them in order. Please can you help me with that, I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248186/discussion-between-king-of-the-hill-and-angelos-gkaraleas).

Comment: As the code is now:
1. Instead of `Node* head; Node* current; Node* prevcurrent;`' make the list hold `Node* head; Node* last`
2. Instead of adding a `Node` and `Data`, function insertAtBack should only have `Data` as an argument
3. In function `insertAtBack` : Create a `Node *new_node = Node(`) and assign to him the given data. If `head` and `last` are `nullptr`, set `head=new_node` and `last=new_node`. Otherwise, call new_node->setHead(last) and then `last= new_node`